# Regex match all words except those between quotes

Tags: python, regex

In this example I want to select all words, except those between quotes (i.e. "results", "items", "packages", "settings" and "build_type", but not "compiler.version").

```
results[0].items[0].packages[0].settings["compiler.version"] 
results[0].items[0].packages[0].settings.build_type
```

Here's what I know: I can target all words with

```
[a-z_]+
```

and then target what's in between quotes with this:

```
(?<=\")[\w.]+(?=\")
```

Is there any way to match the difference between the results of the first and second regex? (i.e. words except if they are surrounded by double quotes)

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/IFrIjO/1)'s a regex playground with the example for convenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match strings between double quotes and then match and capture words optionally followed with dot separated words:

```
list(filter(None, re.findall(r'"[^"]*"|([a-z_]\w*(?:\.[a-z_]\w*)*)', text, re.ASCII | re.I)))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/szbvOE/1). *Details*:

- `"[^"]*"` - a `"` char, zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"` char
- `|` - or
- `([a-z_]\w*(?:\.[a-z_]\w*)*)` - Group 1: a letter or underscore followed with zero or more word chars and then zero or more sequences of a `.` and then a letter or underscore followed with zero or more word chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5D1zgB):

```py
import re
text = 'results[0].items[0].packages[0].settings["compiler.version"] '
print(list(filter(None, re.findall(r'"[^"]*"|([a-z_]\w*(?:\.[a-z_]\w*)*)', text, re.ASCII | re.I))))
# => ['results', 'items', 'packages', 'settings']
```

The `re.ASCII` option is used to make `\w` match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` without accounting for Unicode chars.

Comment: Readers: the technique Wiktor has used has been dubbed by the person behind rexegg.com ("Rex") as [the greatest regex trick ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html). His explanation of the technique is quite good, but I warn you that he spins out thousands of words before getting to the punch line, which is "The trick is that we match what we don't want on the left side of the alternation (the `|`), then we capture what we do want on the right side."

Answer (score 3):

A word is not within a double-quoted substring if and only it is followed in the string by an even number of double-quotes (assuming the string is properly formatted and therefore contains an even number of double-quotes). You can use the following regular expression to match strings that are not contained within double-quoted substrings.

```
[a-z_]+(?=(?:(?:[^\"\n]*\"){2})*[^\"\n]*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sCOnrU/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows (alternatively, hover the cursor over each part of the expression at the link to obtain an explanation of its function).

```
[a-z_]+         # match one or more of the indicated characters
(?=             # begin a positive lookahead
  (?:           # begin an outer non-capture group
    (?:         # begin an inner non-capture group
      [^\"\n]*  # match zero or more characters other than " and \n 
      \"        # match "
    ){2}        # end inner non-capture group and execute twice
  )*            # end outer non-capture group and execute zero or more times
  [^\"\n]*      # match zero or more characters other than " and \n 
  $             # match end of string
)               # end positive lookahead
```

Comment: How come when I'm going through a single line string, it doesn't select anything? Here's what I mean: https://regex101.com/r/TcRpXn/1 Tried to change the formula by removing the last \n, but that didn't help either. Thanks!

Comment: Found a way. For anyone that only needs to go through one line/string without any '\n's, you can use this: `[a-z_]+(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)/gi` formula (basically same as the above, except replacing the last \n for a $). Demo:  https://regex101.com/r/loiAiA/2

Comment: jlo, good catch. I edited. In my original answer I said, "`\n` should be replaced by `(?:\n|$)` if the last line may not have a line terminator.", but I see `$` is sufficient.

Comment: @jlo Just mind the `(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)` is the second worst regex construct ever (the worst one is `(?:\s|.)*?` / `(?:\n|.)*` and suchlike) as it is very inefficient and leads to slowdowns and stack overflow issues. Please use at your own risk, and only with short strings.

Comment: Further to @Wiktor's comment, I took the two lines in the example and converted them to 1,000 alternating lines of each and ran `String#scan` in Ruby against them for my regex and Wiktor's. For my regex it took around it took around 0.03 seconds, for his, around 0.005 seconds...

Comment: ...Wiktor's matches for the first two lines were `[["results"], ["items"], ["packages"], ["settings"], [nil], ["results"], ["items"], ["packages"], ["settings.build_type"]]`. I did not include in the benchmark the extra steps he performs to obtain the desired result, but I don't expect the time for those steps would be significant. This admittedly is a very simple benchmark, but it does suggest that my offering is the tortoise in the race, but it will reach the finish line eventually.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simpler version which works with the example you provided.

```regex
(?<!\")\b[a-z_]+\b(?!\")
```

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/T6d2bi/1)

Edit: This does work for the example you provided. However, it has some flaws because it only avoids matching words that are touching a `"`. Therefore, if you have several words within the quotes, it will match any inner words that are not touching a `"`.

Working on improving this solution and will edit this post if new updates develop.

Comment: This matches `version` in `results[0].settings["compiler.version.two"]`.

Comment: That is right, see [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ZNekP8/1).